# With Rjb to invoke java from ruby:How to send constant params to java class？

Tags: java, ruby, jxl, rjb

I am using JXL.jar to generate Excel from ruby, when I format the cell, I need set the cell format with code like this:
  in java:

`WritableFont font = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 20,
                    WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE,
                    Colour.RED);`

in ruby with Rjb:

```
font_class = Rjb.import("jxl.write.WritableFont")
font       = font_class.new(WritableFont.ARIAL, 20,
                WritableFont.BOLD, false, UnderlineStyle.NO_UNDERLINE,
                Colour.RED)
```

this sure will not work, as ruby does not know WritableFont.ARIAL, so please help to point out how to send WritableFont.ARIAL like constant params to the font_class

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813083/how-to-access-nested-static-classes-using-rjb

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use:

```
font_class = Rjb.import("jxl.write.WritableFont")
color_class = Rjb.import("...Color")  // Use the right color class
font = font_class.new(font_class.ARIAL, 20,
                font_class.BOLD, false, font_class.NO_UNDERLINE,
                color_class.RED)
```